# Need help with a resonant frequency question

Tags: capacitor, inductor, resonance

### I DON'T WANT THE SOLUTION

I just don't understand where the "100" (highlighted) came from.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's angular velocity, omega, which is not given.

Comment: ω=2*pi*f=100 (but units are missing)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I know it's omega I just don't know how did he arrive to the number 100. Why not 377 or 500. That what confused me.

Comment: @OMAR Obviously the frequency must be 50/pi Hz so if you multiply 2*pi*f it equals 100.

Comment: @mais I'll bite...how is it obvious? Everything below the (D) is part of the solution provided later, not part of the question presented to the student. So how do you get the frequency from the single sentence that is the question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I meant it is obvious how to calculate the frequency given ω. But as mentioned by others it is not given in the task. So solving it is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is incomplete, it's missing the frequency. The answer is using 100 rad/s but this is not mentioned in the question (as posted). It may be stated at some other part of the question sheet.

The answer is sloppily written and has a unit discrepancy in the first equation.